# PHP/Database: Find out how many rows have content

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL-statement like this:

```
 $stmtTHIS = $db->query("SELECT titel, done_date FROM task WHERE project = $tID ");
```

How can I find out how many rows have an content in "done_date"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's somewhere over there in the manual. Read the manual

Comment: Do you mean you want to run an SQL COUNT or process the results of this query to work out a count

Comment: Shure, but I my mind "stuck" al little bit :-) Any hint?

Comment: `SELECT count(project) as numrow, titel, done_date FROM task WHERE project = $tID ` numrow will give the number of rows.

Comment: I want process the results of this query to work out a count. The count from the rows where "done_date" have content.

Comment: "an content in "done_date"?" - literally?

Comment: What do you consider valid content

Comment: "done_date" can have a date/string as content or its is empty. I want find out how many have an date in it.

Comment: What will be in this field if it is not a date?

Comment: Its a german-date-formated string. But for this it is important to find out if it is empty or not.

Comment: so, you want to fetch all records and "count" statistics for `done_date`(how many are filled and how many are empty) in one query?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to define what "have content" means then just write a WHERE clause to find those. And use the COUNT function to count the number of rows returned. So lets say "have content" means the field is not null.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task WHERE project = $tID AND done_date IS NOT NULL
```

This counts all the records with that project id and have a value for done_date.

You may also want to check that done_date does not have some other empty value like empty string or 0.

`AND done_date != "" AND done_date !=0`

Alternate:

Use the query you have to get all those rows, then do the count in PHP:

```
 $stmtTHIS = $db->query("SELECT titel, done_date FROM task WHERE project = $tID ");

$count = 0;
while($row = $stmtTHIS->fetchAssoc()){
    //You probably want to do other stiff with the data
    if( !empty($row['done_date']) ){
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

*Your code might be slightly different depending on the DB library your using, (I assumed mysqli)*